# converting snippet of code to another language unnecessary = op?

Tags: java, c++, converters, equals, equality

I have a function of C/C++ code that I wish to convert to Java but am not exactly sure what its trying to due to very little knowledge of the language.

```
public P unknown(int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2)
{
  this._a = this._a < min1 ? min1 : this._a;
  this._a = this._a > max1 ? max1 : this._a;
  this._b = this._b < min2 ? min2 : this._b;
  this._b = this._b > max2 ? max2 : this._b;
  return this;
}
```

What I am wondering is why

```
this._a = this._a
```

Isn't that redundant?
Is the code supposed to do the following in Java?

```
public P unknown(int min1, int max1, int min2, int max2)
{
  this._a < min1 ? this.a = min1 : this.a = this._a;
  this._a > max1 ? this.a = max1 : this.a = this._a;
  this._b < min2 ? this.b = min2 : this.b = this._b;
  this._b > max2 ? this.b = max2 : this.b = this._b;
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Minimal detail, but in Java is not nice to use "_" as a tagging for private fields. Uncommon, not wrong, but ugly nonetheless.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this._a = this._a` does not appear as a complete statement anywhere. The expression is part of the statement that contains the ternary operator

```
this._a = this._a < min1 ? min1 : this._a;
```

so the statement isnt actually redundant.

Read: [The Conditional (or Ternary) Operator (?:)](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/)

Comment: I think you could emphasize the precedence; this will help understand the meaning of the statement (difference between `?:` and `if`)

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is basically an if statement built into a single expression;

```
if X ? do y : else do z

this._a = this._a < min1 ? min1 : this._a;
assign    comparison       then   else
```

Incidentally the method you are trying to convert is actually already completely valid Java, you shouldn't need to do anything with it! As it happens everything in that method is the same in both languages.

Comment: No it's not and that's actually *the* problem of the OP. It's not a statement but an expression. The difference is crucial.

Comment: It's an if statement (the same functionality) built into an expression. The if is something the OP will be familiar with and gives them context for what the ? : does.

Answer (score 1):

it's not redundant, but just a formatting of the language.

```
this._a = (this._a < min1) ? min1 : this._a;
```

means that the program will compare `_a` with `min1`, assigning the first value after the `?` if true or the latter, if false.

Your java snippet does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't understand the ternary operator correctly. It's not a conditional block of statement(s) but rather a conditional **expression**.

It's not:

```
(condition) ? (what to do in case of true) : (what to do otherwise)
```

but rather

```
(condition) ? (what the expression evaluates to in case of true) : (what otherw.)
```

so the `... ? ... : ...` part is only a **value** which is in your program then assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not doing `this._a = this._a`, that will be silly. It is using ternary operator. 
This is the way to read, hope it makes sense to you :

```
this._a = (this._a < min1 ? min1 : this._a);
```